# Is there any way to change the datatype of a field when generated a table through @Entity Annotation in JPA Springboot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, uuid

How to change the data type of the field when generated through @Entity Annotation using JPA and SpringBoot? I have a class name as Product which contains a field name as productId having a data type of UUID and JPA generated the field of type binary.

Comment: Have you tried javax.persistence.Column Annotation with a ColumnDefinition inside it?

Comment: Yes, it also didn't work. In ColumnDefinition I tried to use "TEXT" and that didn't work. Do you know in MySQL is there any data type which can support UUID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to use @Type annotation with type field sets to "uuid-char" and it solved the problem. Please find below snippet.

**@Type(type = "uuid-char)
UUID productId;**